# How can I search for team members and add/remove from Glip teams?

Tags: ringcentral, glip

I need to find organization members and add/remove them from Glip teams.

There is also an API to update Group members using the `personId` and email properties, but no info on how to search or get a list of `personId`s for the organization.

- Edit Group Members API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Chats-assignGlipGroupMembers

In the API Reference, I found an API to list teams but not to list people.

- Get Team List API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Chats-listGlipTeams

Is there a way to list organization members and add/remove them from Glip teams?

Comment: There is this deprecated API: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Chats-assignGlipGroupMembers

Have you tried that? 

I work at RC, let me see what I can dig up.

Comment: The link to the deprecated Edit Group Members has been added. We still need to know how to search the `personId` for everyone in the org. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of Glip organization members, use the Directory Entries API to search and list company contacts. The user `id` returned in the Directory Entries API is the same as used for the Edit Group Members API.

Search or list company contacts using the following APIs:

- Search Company Directory Entries API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Company-Contacts-searchDirectoryEntries
- Get Company Directory Entries API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Company-Contacts-listDirectoryEntries

Use the returned user objects' `id` property with the Edit Group Members API in the `addedPersonIds` and `removedPersonIds` properties.

- Edit Group Members API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Chats-assignGlipGroupMembers